# iOS Multiple Columns in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have multiple rows and columns of data. But iPhone UITableView contains only single column and multiple rows. How do I display my multi column data following Apple's Human Interface Guidelines?

Comment: Someone else is hosting that page now: http://usxue.is-programmer.com/posts/14176.html

Comment: You asked specifically about UITableView, but consider using a UIWebView with an HTML table, which might make things easy.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to build it by your own, or use a library, like [UIGridView](https://github.com/tanin47/UIGridView).
(I'm the creator)

You can learn the source code of [UIGridView](https://github.com/tanin47/UIGridView). It's really short.

Comment: Please include the code of UIGridView in your answer, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for something that looks like an Excel spreadsheet then I would recommend the `MDSpreadview` class.  The source is available at http://mochidev.com/open.  It looks pretty slick but bogs down if you have a lot of data to display.

Other than that, you should probably just create your own `UITableViewCell`. It's pretty easy with the new Storyboards of iOS5 and you can handle millions of cells of data.

Answer (score 1):

For those interested, I just updated [MDSpreadView](https://github.com/mochidev/MDSpreadViewDemo) to be *much* faster, and it supports practically an unlimited number of rows and columns (up until `CGFloat` stops being accurate to the pixel) with an API very similar to `UITableView`. More info on [my site](http://mochidev.com/open)