# Indexing a matrix of objects (UILabel)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, for-loop, uilabel

I have a collection of objects (UILabel) named as in a matrix.

Ex:

```
A11    A12    A13    A14    ...
A21    A22    A23    A24    ...
A31    A32    A33    A34    ...
...    ...    ...    ...
```

I was thinking to using a easy for-loop to set the text:

```
for (int i=1; i==5; i++) {
    for (int y=1; y==5; y++) {
        //code
    }
}
```

There is a way to do it in that way? Something like this...

```
Aiy.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"A%d%d", i, y];
```

EDIT:
Maybe I didn't explain my problem clearly, i'm sorry...

I would like to do something like this (please forgive the code-blasphemy!)

```
A(@"%d",i)(@"%d",y).text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"A%d%d", i, y];
```

and put that stuff in the for-loop so i can change the text of all the labels (Label `A11` will have "A11" as text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to access the label given it's property name...

Inside your loop, try:

```
// Get label's name
NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"A%d%d", i, y];

// Get label from class given it's name
UILabel *label = [self valueForKey:name];

// Set the contents
label.text = name;
```

Comment: You made my day! Actually I gave up with that solution and found another way, but I'll save this for another project! Thanks a lot *bro fist*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand your problem. Maybe the response is:

```
for (int i=1; i<=5; i++) {
    for (int y=1; y<=5; y++) {
        Aiy.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"A%d%d", i, y];;
    }
}
```

That's what you want?

Comment: instead of Aiy, i would like to put there all my objects (A11, A12, ...). I was asking if it's possible to use variables as part of the file name... like     `A(@"%d",i)(@"%d",y).text = blablabla`

Comment: Ok. I think you can't. But why don't you use multi-dimensions array?

Comment: Well... my main problem is: I have a matrix of 9x5... do I have to create 45 objects in interface builder, or there is better way?

Comment: It's definitely not a good way passing by IB to do this. There's a lot of ways using code to dynamically create and add to your view your objects as subviews (like UILabel).

Comment: Could you please link me one of those... It's not that I'm lazy, but I really have no idea on what to search.

Comment: If I have to do this, I may use a `UITableView` as a GridView customizing `UITableViewCell` in it. This has the advantage in addition to optimize the display by recycling the cells. It's just a personal suggestion among others. See some topics about it like: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855857/how-to-display-multiple-columns-in-a-uitableview) or [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252682/multiple-columns-in-tableview). And store your considered data in 2 imbricated `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray` as x and y axis, depending on whether the number of data is always fixed or not