# Pinterest Gridview implementation on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, pinterest

I want to implement a grid view like the one in Pinterest [image]

I thought about implementing as 3 table views. But I was not able to scroll them together well. When I implemented the `scrollViewDidScroll` and set the `contentOffset` for the table views other the scrollView , the scrolling became slow and unusable.

Another implementation I did was of was having a set of images to load and calling the viewDraw function in `scrollViewDidScroll`. The `ViewDraw` function just draws the necessary images and removes the rest of the images from  the memory which were already drawn but wont be visible . 
this too makes the ScrollView scrolling slow. And another issue with it is that there are white(background color) patches before the images are drawn.

What should be the best way to implement this grid view ?

Comment: just use one table view and make multiple columns in tableView. Add image to each column as you need.use these tutorials http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855857/how-to-display-multiple-columns-in-a-uitableview , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252682/multiple-columns-in-tableview

Comment: But that wont work right ?. Since the images are not aligned as always. Some images longer than others.

Comment: just use scaleToFit property of UIView (UIImageView in your case)

Answer (score 3):

**Solution 1** (i don't know if this works and I don't like it very much)

How about having 3 vertical table views side by side,  but forward any touch events from any tableview to the other ones. I understand that you had performance problems when trying to sync the tableviews, but maybe working on an event level things would work better. Maybe.

**Solution 2**

Use a UIScrollView (for the scrolling purposes of course). For performance and memory reasons you also need to implement a load-on-demand mechanism so that you don't load all your images at once.

To do this I would create a class, CustomImageStrip that handles a vertical image list. This class works together with the scrollview and uses `contentOffset` to decide when it is time to load/unload a image from the strip.

By having 3 independent image strip classes, the images can be of any size and don't need to be aligned. But, since they all belong to the same UIScrollView the scrolling will be done simultaneously.

Comment: Second solution seems to be more pinterest like, as they layout the images by the height (the "nextToShow" image goes to the column that has less height at the time of lying it out). But it needs more attention to details and it needs to create the dequeueing mechanism  for those custom views (for memory consumption purposes).

Comment: Indeed, you need to implement the dequeueing mechanism, but it's not that complicated as it sounds. As opposed to solution 1, I think it's much simpler :)

Comment: I've done something similar to first solution once with two tables (one main, for the whole screen and second, index style, but with images). The performance issues I had, was because of the main table (cell height was bigger than the screen. I've ended up by splitting the cell), not because of two tables and synchronizing them... By the way, can you give me some example of the dequeueing mechanism?