# How could I create a tiled photo gallery of different widths and heights?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, user-interface, ios5

I've been looking to create a photo gallery for an iPad app, where the images are of varying widths and heights. Rather than cropping them to fit in a grid-view, I'd like to create a "mosaic" effect as seen in the [Pinterest](http://reviewholes.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/Pinterest-Coming-soon-in-iPad.jpg) and [Jetsetter](http://www.blogcdn.com/www.gadling.com/media/2011/08/ipad1.jpg) app (see links for reference images)

Any idea where I could start to create an effect like this?

Comment: I haven't done this but my first impression is that it's a lot easier for pinterest as the images are arranged in columns and in each column, an image is fitted below a previous image. It's tricky for Jetsetter, though, if it's all done dynamically according to image sizes.

Comment: Talking about the Pinterest case, are you envisioning it doing something like looping through images, placing them, recalculating the space left to the right, finding the next image with that width or less..., etc?

Comment: Yeah...sort of. Basically, I was thinking that one could draw the images being looped through by resizing the images to a fixed width(width of each column). So you don't need to calculate the spaces to the left/right, only on the top and bottom. This cannot be the case with JetSetter!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pinterest Gridview implementation on iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260099/pinterest-gridview-implementation-on-ios)

Answer (score 1):

For variable height a la Pinterest, the easiest way to go about this is to use a `UITableView` for each column, as it already provides the mechanism to insert/delete images using `UITableViewRowAnimation`s. It's easier if the height of the image is known, because `UITableView` asks for it before loading cells. But if it isn't, what you can do is insert each cell sequentially (head or tail) to the **shortest** UITableView. Load the image, resize if necessary. Disk-cache the heights so you don't have to load the image for every cell. I've successfully implemented it this way.

Addendum: part of the trick in using 3 (or more) UITableViews is to manually sync the scrolling. Otherwise they would scroll on its own:

```
#pragma mark - UIScrollView stuff
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)inScrollView {
    // Sync the scrolling of all table views
    CGPoint offset = inScrollView.contentOffset;

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < self.tableViews.count; i++) {
        PLAlbumTableView *tableView = [self.tableViews objectAtIndex:i];
        if (tableView != inScrollView)
            tableView.contentOffset = offset;

    }
}

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)inScrollView {
    // Sync the scrolling of all table views
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < self.tableViews.count; i++) {
        PLAlbumTableView *tableView = [self.tableViews objectAtIndex:i];
        if (tableView != inScrollView)
            [tableView setContentOffset:tableView.contentOffset animated:NO];
    }
}
```