# How do I add multiple columns in my table in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

How do I add multiple columns in my table in iPhone SDK?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at this link.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/506601/iphone-multiple-columns-in-uitableview.. This link http://usxue.is-programmer.com/posts/14176.html has the code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently UITableView doesn't have the support to have multiple columns in table view cell. So, you can not add multiple columns in UITableView. But there are some alternates, like drawing custom grids on table view cells.

Have a look at this post.. [iPhone Multiple Columns in UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506601/iphone-multiple-columns-in-uitableview).. This link http://usxue.is-programmer.com/posts/14176.html has the code..