# Customize column of table view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

Is it possible to customize the column of table view.
By default table view contains 1 column, But according to my requirement I want 4 column in table.
Means I want table like we create in MS-word/excel.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone Multiple Columns in UITableView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/506601/iphone-multiple-columns-in-uitableview),http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791451/how-do-i-add-multiple-columns-in-my-table-in-iphone-sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://dewpoint.snagdata.com/2008/10/31/drawing-a-grid-in-a-uitableview/

ad

http://usxue.is-programmer.com/posts/14176.html

will help you

Answer (score 0):

No there is no such method to do that ..... but for sure u can make a subclass of `UITableViewCell` such that it has 4 parts in it and all parts are seperated by a fine line (a kind of bordered image as background will do the job). You can manage your data accordingly and it may create an illusion of MS-word/excel.

But I am sure you are aware of column and row of UITableView, so you can manage all your data is this format. If you want to represent data in tabular fashion like MS-word/excel you don't have enough space as width on iPhone and If you incorporate a tableView in a scroll view, two scroll will not be user friendly.

So i suggest you to go with TableView's native behaviour for such type of task.