# How to make a-two-column UITableViewController list?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I need to present my table view with a two column list. I read some related posts about making some grid by overriding drawRect ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506601/iphone-multiple-columns-in-uitableview)). However, I'm seeking a simple way to design my cell with IB in nib, then load it and push two cells on each row. The example with drawRect is not appropriate because it involves manual setting of positions. I just need to push those two cells with some autosizing, that's it. Is it possible?

I'm looking for something like (in cellForRowAtIndexPath):

```
cell.contentView = emptyUIViewContainer;
[cell.contentView addSubview:FirstColumnUIView];
[cell.contentView addSubview:SecondColumnUIView];
```

I don't need to have two separate nibs for those two columns because every column is of the same format just with some other data. Any ideas?

UPDATE: Intuitively, I'm trying to do something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
  UITableViewCell *cell1 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if (cell1 == nil) {
    cell1 = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
  }
  // Configure the first cell.
  cell1.textLabel.text = ...some text

  // Configure the second cell
  UITableViewCell *cell2 = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
  cell2.textLabel.text = ...some text

  //set row as container for two cells    
  UITableViewCell *twoColumnRowView = [[UIView alloc] init]; //initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 20)];

  cell1.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 20);
  [twoColumnRowView addSubview:cell1];
  cell2.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(100, 0, 100, 20);
  [twoColumnRowView addSubview:cell2];

  return twoColumnRowView; // cell;
}
```

It's just a raw prototype I'm playing with now. But the code crashes at runtime with "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setTableViewStyle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"

UPDATE 2. I have changed a code to look more practical. Strange but after several tries I got the app working without crash but with weird black background in all cells. Here is the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *FirstCellIdentifier = @"FirstCellIdentifier"; 
  static NSString *SecondCellIdentifier = @"SecondCellIdentifier";

  // initialize first cell
  UITableViewCell *cell1 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:FirstCellIdentifier];

  if (cell1 == nil) {
    cell1 = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:FirstCellIdentifier] autorelease];
  }

  //initialize second cell
  UITableViewCell *cell2 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SecondCellIdentifier];

  if (cell2 == nil) {
    cell2 = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:SecondCellIdentifier] autorelease];
  }

  cell1.textLabel.text = ...data
  cell2.textLabel.text = ...data

  UITableViewCell *twoColumnRowView = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];

  [twoColumnRowView addSubview:cell1];
  //cell2.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(100, 0, 100, 20);
  [twoColumnRowView addSubview:cell2];

  return twoColumnRowView; // cell;
}
```

I'm not reusing twoColumnRowView but both other does do.

Comment: Does each column need to be an independent cell? Can you just add subviews to a normal cell and populate them independently? What sort of behaviour do you want to see on editing, selection etc?

Comment: Yes, each column should be as independent cell-item, that I will use when sorting. Cell as item will contain custom objects (buttons, images) that will be accessible with tapping. The thing is I need to have a rotatable table. In portrait mode I need to show one column per row, and need to show two-columns in landscape mode. Currently I'm trying to get the code working in landscape mode with two-cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't (or at least, shouldn't) put two table views next to each other. And, as you already know, a table view only ever has a single column.

However, you can put as much data as you want in each cell.

You can do most of this in Interface Builder. Create a XIB with a `UITableViewCell`. Drag and drop a couple of `UILabel`s into the right place. You could update the labels by finding them with the `viewWithTag:` method, but it would be better to create a custom `UITableViewCell` class with properties pointing to each label.

Since tables are so central to UIKit, there are a lot of samples in Apple's documentation set and some good WWDC talks. You can download the videos from iTunes.

Comment: Yes, I do understand that a table can have only one column and I can put as much data in a cell as I want. So, I'm thinking to nest two cells into CellContainer and return it from cellForRowAtIndexPath. You can see it from my UPDATED code. The code I'm trying does all stuff from code (without nib) but still I'm unable to achieve that nesting. Am I breaking the rules of  cell construction with that code?

Comment: Why use two `UITableViewCell`s when you can have one cell and two `UILabel`s?

Comment: Also, why are you adding new `UITableViewCell`s every time the cell is displayed?! If you _have_ to do it this way (you don't) at least only add the subviews once.

Comment: I need to have a rotatable table. In portrait mode I need to show one column per row, and need to show two-columns in landscape mode. Yes, the the cells are not reused in my code, just experimenting with the code. Strange but after several tries the code stopped crashing but I have all cells in black background color without.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you...

> http://www.iphonedevx.com/?p=153

else the best way is to put two table views side by side, if they need to scroll independently.

Hope this will help you...

Comment: This is the same example I mentioned in my post that involves drawRect. Two table views side-by-side are not suitable for my current task :(