# Making UITableView look more like a "conventional" table, with multiple columns

Tags: ios, uitableview, user-interface

I have a pretty much standard `UITableView`, but I would like to change it to look like what would be considered a normal table outside iOS development -- make it have more columns (but just one row) and make the cells square-shaped.
I thought about making more tables (one for every cell) and then placing them next to each other, but that wouldn't be so convenient.

**Is there maybe a simple way to make cells go on the right of the one before instead of going below?**

Comment: [Take a look at this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/506601/iphone-multiple-columns-in-uitableview). The older answers are bogus or invalid links, but there's a few Open Source libraries listed in the newer answers.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann thanks, it seems applicable!  
But do You maybe know how could I simply make the cells align horizontally after one another instead of vertically (below each other)?

Answer (score 1):

Use some third-party classes that allows you to have "Grid Views".

One is my [`OHGridView`](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHGridView) class, another is [`NRGridView`](https://github.com/ldesroziers/NRGridView), and there are many more. If your app needs to be compatible with iOS4 and/or iOS5, using a third party class (or building one yourself) is the only option.

Under iOS6, there will be some other stuff that allow you to do that directly (iOS6 still under NDA so we can't talk about it publicly yet, but go read the API Diff files in the developer.apple.com website if you have access to them). So if your app is intended to be compatible only starting iOS6+ and you don't need support for iOS5, this could be the solution and you should go read about it if you have a developer account with access to the iPs6 SDK.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for us UICollectionView.

Comment: Indeed but iOS6 only, and it is still under NDA

Comment: Only until Wednesday. And buy the time that you actually implement what you're looking to do and get it on the store, iOS 6 will be a significant part of the install base. I think you'd be fine to start an app at iOS 6 and beyond.

Comment: I didn't say you shouldn't use it. I just said it's illegal to talk about it in public before wednesday as the NDA you agreed when you bought the Apple Developer Program stipulates it. But he can still read the documentation if he has an official Apple account, or go talk about it on the official Apple forum. (I agree a lot of people are already talking about all these features in public, but that does not means they have the right to do it, the NDA is pretty clear about that, and as responsible SO users we should be strict about legal issues)

Comment: I was talking to the OP. Thanks for your concern.