# Make UITableView's cells align horizontally instead of vertically

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Making UITableView look more like a “conventional” table, with multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449296/making-uitableview-look-more-like-a-conventional-table-with-multiple-columns)

I made a normal `UITableView` that displays its cells one below another but I want it to align them horizontally instead

I thought about making more tables (one for every cell) and then placing these next to each other, but that wouldn't be so convenient.

Simply said, how to make cells go on the right of the one before instead of going below?

Comment: You already have a same question like this? why are you asking again?

Comment: I'm sorry, I couldn't find that one and I thought I should post it again. I will close it now as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, a UITableView is limited to a single column.  In the official [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html), it says: "A table view in the UIKit framework is limited to a single column because it is designed for a device with a small screen."
If you really want to have multiple cells in a row and use UITableView, you could just create a custom UITableViewCell.  But I don't know the context in which you are trying to create this, so there may be a even better alternative.