# Create 2 column in UITableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone Multiple Columns in UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506601/iphone-multiple-columns-in-uitableview)

Anyone help how to  create 2 column tableview in ios?

Comment: please elaborate. What is your actual requirement

Comment: This may help you out.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/506601/iphone-multiple-columns-in-uitableview

Comment: i need to display 2 images in sigle row of tableview and get the value of selected image?

Comment: i have done to display 2 images but i cant get the value of particular image

Comment: You can use single tableview and do a custom tableviewcell with two labels side by side which will look like two columns ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create custom cell view for this task. And add this custom cell in yourTable View.

Check this link for more info [Link](http://usxue.is-programmer.com/posts/14176.html)  [Link 2](http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/how-to-design-a-custom-uitableviewcell-from-scratch/1292/)

According to your query you just make customButton instead of images and then set image and `tagValue` to that button, so whenever you will press button you can identify using `tagValue`.

For yourTable Row

```
bt1.tag = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d0",indexPath.row];
bt2.tag = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d1",indexPath.row];
```

and then manipulate this..:)

Comment: i have done to display 2 images but i cant get the value of particular image

Comment: Assume  i have display 4 images in first row i have display "image1" and "image2" and in second row i have display  "image3" and "image4" now i have clicked "image3"  how i know image3 was clicked?

Comment: just set button instead of image..and five tag like button.tag = 01; and on this buttonPress event you can identfy'

Comment: yeah i have tried that i can identify whether clicked first button or second button for each rows but i can't identify which rows first button or which rows second button

Comment: y i cant able to come stack overflow chat rajneesh

Comment: mano has only 11 reputation, not yet enough to chat..you need 20 reputation....

Comment: now you have 16 point, now you can do upvoting... enjoy :)

Comment: can you help me to get 20 points

Comment: Yup why not .., enjoy now :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20511/discussion-between-mano-and-rajneesh071)

Comment: where are you from mano?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to create two table views and place them side by side. Make yourself the delegate and dataSource of both, and when one is scrolled scroll the other to match pragmatically. This will give the user the impression that the table view has two columns. Then, when figuring out what cells to give to the tables you just need to examine the `tableView` argument to determine what is what.

Comment: do u have any sample code for this?

Comment: Not at the moment, no, but it is simple. Just, instead of one table view create two. Then make yourself the delegate/dataSource of both and slap them into your interface side by side. To detect scrolling, AFAIK just adhere to the `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol and implement the correct methods to see when the user is scrolling and programmatically scroll the other. It might lag behind a bit, IDK since I've never done it. When you're asked for cells, just inspect the table view (maybe give them seperate tags) to see which one is asking for a cell, then give it the correct cell from your model.