# Creating columns with new indexpaths in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

have gone through

[Create 2 column in UITableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13678364/create-2-column-in-uitableview)

[iPhone Multiple Columns in UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506601/iphone-multiple-columns-in-uitableview) those links.

but I want to create a cell with different indexpaths exactly image attached.

[image] is it possible to do like this. Since my layout and content both are dynamic I wont be able to do it in a single indexpath.

Comment: For that, you may want to use UICollectionView that does exactly that.

Comment: or you can use a horizontal scroll view inside the table view cell.

Comment: @user3752753 I didn't get you. Why do we need scroll view here?

Comment: you can add any number of items in each row, making it more dynamic.

Comment: @user3752753 Have you read my question?